# Where does Postman save your local collections on a mac?

Tags: postman

I recently was looking to recover my Postman collections that I had saved locally on my macbook. I created a new user and wanted to copy my data over from my old user.

I saw this question asked for Windows, but struggled to find a current answer for mac.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar situation where I had a local workspace of collections. When I signed in to my account I lost all my local collections.

I navigated to `/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Postman/`
and there were a number of backups with the naming convention 'backup-yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss' e.g `backup-2021-06-30T15-02-29`.

Importing this into my logged in account managed to salvage the majority of my  local collections.

Comment: When doing this - people should make sure to restore a pre-sign-in backup, because postman creates a new backup without any of the old collections after the first sign in

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I believe the collection data is saved in the IndexedDB directory in `/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Postman/IndexedDB`

I was able to restore all my Postman data and settings by deleting the `/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Postman` directory for my new user, and copying the old version of that directory, which included the DB of my collections.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on version 9.2.0 and if you go to Preferences->Data you see an Export Data button.

[image: export data]